# Cannot create table with JPA Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm new to JPA. I am following this guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-hibernate

I am using H2 database and Intellij Idea. According to the guide @Entity annotation would create book table.

Entity class:

[image: My entity class]

Database connection:

[image]

Logs:

[image: Logs]

[image: Logs]

application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Comment: Why do you think the table is not created?

Comment: @Jens i can't see the table and can't make queries.

Comment: The tables will be deleted after the application stops as i know

Comment: provide a repo with a code example, I would see how your spring context was created. But first, try to connect to your in-memory database via some SQL client and check manually the SQL schema.

Comment: @Eugene Maksymets I started to code with spring initializer. The database is in-memory.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information: the `pom.xml`, your complete `application.properties` (or `application.yml`) files and the full logging output when you run the application. Don't paste images, paste as text.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Soln: make sure your entity / Model class class is within you com.package package. otherwise it will run the classes and never map the entities.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLX7J.png)

for my case I had to make sure it under the com  package and not java package

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).